# Copy readonly files in workspace - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

As part of build it is copying and overwriting few binaries which are checked into repository. When i do manual build things are perfect, however through jenkins the files are not being replaced.

Looks like entire workspace(Cloned Repo) is readonly. Is there a way to make workspace editable in jenkins.

Using batch/powershell command to remove readonly attibute would be tedious i assume. Any better solutions.

Comment: which repo are you using ??

Comment: TFS. and Code is in .c#

Comment: Why do you want to replace the files in the workspace ?? why not just copy the new binaries and push it into the repo ??

Comment: Actually as part of build it generates dlls and places in some folder within workspace. Then those newly generated dlls are referenced in building other successive projects

Comment: generally jenkins will have complete access to the work space... that's why the code is copied into the folder... so Jenkins does have write permission... can you do an `ls` in the work space and that particular folder and see if jenkins has access ?? If it does then, i'm guessing you are trying to copy the files while the build is still happening... Try to copy it after the build is completed

Comment: Another solution would be to keep the generated DDL's in a separate/newly generated folder and reference it from there